# XPath: Get underlying text for cases with and without a tag

Tags: xpath, scrapy

Is there a way to combine these both XPath into one?

`//li[@itemprop="worksFor"]/span/div/a/text()`

`//li[@itemprop="worksFor"]/span/div/text()`

Background is that I want to see the organization in my scrapings, but the way its rendered varies:
https://github.com/wencakisa (with `a` tag)

> Expected result: @HackSoftware

https://github.com/djangofan (without `a` tag)

> Expected result: The Standard Insurance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//li[@itemprop="worksFor"]/span/div//text()
```

Comment: Ah, so the catch is just adding `//`?

Comment: This will match both, but can also match other tags in between, like '//li[@itemprop="worksFor"]/span/div/p/text()'. So it depends on your needs.

Answer (score 0):

```py
from lxml.html import fromstring

temp = response.xpath('//li[@itemprop="worksFor"]/span/div').get()
fromstring(temp).text_content().strip()
```

Default parser in `scrapy` is `parsel`, which act as an API uppon `lxml`. No additional dependencies.

`fromstring()` returns an `lxml.html.HtmlElement`. `HtmlElement.text_content()` iterate all elements/nodes within current node, and concatenate all text.

`lxml.html.HtmlElement`

- `.iter()`
- `.iter_text()`
- `.text_content()`